# Transformation to change column alignment in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a package, that picks excel file from a location and loads to a table in sql server.(The Excel file is derived from another package)
The Excel file has columns with name A,B,C,D.
I want the columns to be aligned like A,B,D,C ( C & D sequence changed). Is there a way I can achieve this in SSIS? The person dropping the file does not want to manually change it.
Currently I have data flow as: 
Excel Source Plus --> Row Count --> OLEDB Destination

Thanks :)

Comment: Excel, your source, has column A, B, C, D. You load that to a table that has columns A, B, C, D. The desire is ...what? To make the table's columns in the order A, B, D, C?

Comment: The excel source should have  columns A,B,D,C since the table has columns in order A,B,D,C. But the Excel currently has columns in order A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 1):

You can map fields in your destination in any order you wish.  The columns can be in different positions or even have different names.